# Vue3 updating values between components

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a basic SPA with two child components, a header and a side menu (left drawer).

I wish the user to be able to click a button on the header component to call a function in the side menu component.

I understand I can use props to access a variable between parent & child components however how can I update a value between two sibling components?

**Header**

```
<q-btn dense flat round icon="menu" @click="toggleLeftDrawer" />
```

**Left Drawer**

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  setup () {
    const leftDrawerOpen = ref(false)

    return {
      leftDrawerOpen,
      toggleLeftDrawer () {
        leftDrawerOpen.value = !leftDrawerOpen.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Through a common parent. Probably with global store. See https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

Comment: so have both the function & variable in the parent? I was hoping to avoid using a store for this.

Comment: Yes, it's cleaner to have both. It shouldn't be necessarily a store as separate entity. But any way the state should be contained in parent comp

Comment: Am I able to use a custom even in the header component that the left menu responds to? Os is this getting too complex?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I was wondering if I could fire a custom event in the header that is actioned in the side menu however I have since read that the parent receives the event.

Comment: You can bind store value directly in a template or use a watcher if you need to be notified in comp script

Answer (score 0):

Use global stores. Create a file
`/store.js` (you can obviously use any name)
Inside this file store/write the following code:-

```
import { reactivity } from 'vue'

export const global = reactive({
   yourVariable: 'initialValue'
})
```

You can then import this variable and interact with it from anywhere and the change will be global. See the code below:

**In header component:-**

```
<script setup>
  import { global } from './store.js'
  const clicked = ()=> {
      global.yourVariable = 'changed'
  }
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="clicked">
  </button>
</template>
```

**In leftDrawer Component:-**

```
<script setup>
  import { global } from './store.js'
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ global.yourVariable }}
    <!--You'll see the change:)-->
  </div>
</template>
```

**Then add these two in your main vue:-**

```
<script setup>
  import headerComponent from '...'
  import leftDrawerComponent from '....'

  //....
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <header-component />
    <left-drawer-component />
  </div>
</template>
```